# Visualize histograms in seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn, distribution

I have a code that create 16 histograms. My problems are:

1. I think the code is too much repetative and that there are ways to write it shorter.
   2.I have 13 fields to create histograms, and as 13 is prime number, I face a problem how to show all of them nicely but without blank plots.
2. I want to show the distribution but I get only 1 bar, even though I have change dit to 0, 100 and 500 (I have more than 1000 observations).
3. some columns are float and have too many 0 after the dot and I can't change it.

This is my code:

```
f, axes = plt.subplots(4, 4, figsize=(20,20), sharex=True)
sns.distplot(data['HR90'], color="skyblue", ax=axes[0,0],bins=500)
sns.distplot(data['HC90'], color="olive", ax=axes[0,1],bins=100)
sns.distplot(data['RD90'], color="gold", ax=axes[0,2],bins=100)
sns.distplot(data['PO90'], color="teal", ax=axes[0,3], bins=100)

sns.distplot(data['PS90'], color="red", ax=axes[1,0], bins=100)
sns.distplot(data['UE90'], color="green", ax=axes[1,1], bins=100)
sns.distplot(data['DV90'], color="blue", ax=axes[1,2], bins=100)
sns.distplot(data['MA90'], color="purple", ax=axes[1,3], bins=100)

sns.distplot(data['POL90'], color="orange", ax=axes[2,0], bins=100)
sns.distplot(data['DNL90'], color="green", ax=axes[2,1], bins=100)
sns.distplot(data['BLK90'], color="pink", ax=axes[2,2], bins=100)
sns.distplot(data['GI89'], color="silver", ax=axes[2,3], bins=100)

sns.distplot(data['FH90'], color="cyan", ax=axes[3,1], bins=100)
```

and this is the results:

[image]

as you can see I have some empty plots and the bins look like one.

Comment: What happens when you do not specify any bins? So just let seaborn figure out how many bins you need

Comment: @marc I get the same results, it seems like "bins" doesn't affect it at all

Comment: Because to me it seems it could be working correctly, however the x-axis is set to show so much that your histograms get compressed to a 'single' bar. If you zoom in on the lines I expect you to see a smooth line. Does your data hold extreme outliers?

Comment: @Marc on SPSS it doesn't look like this. is there any way to limit the X axis?

Comment: sns.distplot() returns a matplotlib.axes object which you can manipulate. look at https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html for more information. What I would start with though would be to change the sharex to False. When you look at the figure on top right you see a little bump which is probably messing everything up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

position = []
for x in range(0, 4):
    for y in range (0, 4):
        position.append([x, y])

groups = ['PO90', 'HC90', 'RD90', 'HR90', 'PS90', 'UE90', 'DV90', 'MA90', 'POL90', 'DNL90', 'BLK90', 'GI89','FH90']
graph_colors = ["skyblue", "olive", "gold", "teal", "red", "green", "blue", "purple", "orange", "green", "pink", "silver", "cyan"]
graph_bins = [500, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100]

data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=(100, 13)), columns=groups)

f, axes = plt.subplots(4, 4, figsize=(20,20), sharex=False, sharey=False)

for i in range(0, 13):
    sns.distplot(data[groups[i]], color=graph_colors[i], ax=axes[position[i][0], position[i][1]], bins=graph_bins[i])
```

The plot will look like this:

[image]

To get rid of the empty plot, sub plots must be added in a slightly different way, like so:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))

# Generating 1st column.
for sp_index in range(1, 14, 4):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(4, 4, sp_index)
    sns.distplot(data[groups[sp_index-1]], color=graph_colors[sp_index-1], ax=ax, bins=graph_bins[sp_index-1])

# Generating 2nd column. 
for sp_index in range(2, 14, 4):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(4, 4, sp_index)
    sns.distplot(data[groups[sp_index-1]], color=graph_colors[sp_index-1], ax=ax, bins=graph_bins[sp_index-1])

# Generating 3rd column.
for sp_index in range(3, 14, 4):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(4, 4, sp_index)
    sns.distplot(data[groups[sp_index-1]], color=graph_colors[sp_index-1], ax=ax, bins=graph_bins[sp_index-1])

# Generating 4thcolumn.
for sp_index in range(4, 14, 4):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(4, 4, sp_index)
    sns.distplot(data[groups[sp_index-1]], color=graph_colors[sp_index-1], ax=ax, bins=graph_bins[sp_index-1])
```

Then the plot will look like this (N.B. the graphs will look slightly different to the version above, since the data frame values were generated, using `np.random.randint` function several times, whilst experimenting with the solution):

[image]

Comment: this code doesn't work ,it has syntax error and after fixing them I have gotten this :ValueError: Location based indexing can only have [integer, integer slice (START point is INCLUDED, END point is EXCLUDED), listlike of integers, boolean array] types

Comment: Sorry - I haven't tested the code. Now I have came up with a solution. Please Try. I have also generated a dataframe to test the code on.

P.S. The issue was an obvious syntax errors e.g. missing the `in` operator but most importantly it was in specifying the position in the `axes` object.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

I had to change the sharex and sharey :

```
f, axes = plt.subplots(4, 4, figsize=(60,60), sharex=False, sharey=False)
```

This way the don't share the same axes and it works